# Unable to run method mutiple times, won't compile

Tags: java

I wrote a program that replicates a carnival game for my java class.  There are 5 dice with 4, 6, 8, 12 and 20 sides.  I have to simulate playing the game 100 times and count up the wins.  The code for running it once works fine.  I can't get it to run 100 times.

I'm getting these errors when I compile:
[line: 15]
Error: The method dieRoll(int, int, int, int, int) in the type Carnival is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[line: 17]
Error: dieRoll cannot be resolved to a variable

I'm trying a for function using

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){dieRoll(i);} 
{
System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieRoll);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Here's the entire program:

```
public class Carnival
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{     

  int dice1=(int)(4*Math.random()+1);
  int dice2=(int)(6*Math.random()+1);
  int dice3=(int)(8*Math.random()+1);
  int dice4=(int)(12*Math.random()+1);
  int dice5=(int)(20*Math.random()+1);

  System.out.println(dieRoll(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5));
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){dieRoll(i);}       //Here is where I have the
                                                  //errors       
  {
  System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieRoll);  //And here
  }

  }//end main

   public static int dieRoll(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3, int dice4, int
   dice5) 
   {
   return dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4 + dice5; 
   }//end method  
   }//end class
```

Comment: that is obvious, why are you calling dieRoll with just one parameter, it is defined to take 5 parameters?

Comment: `dieRoll` is a method that receives 5 parameters. You can't use it like `dieRoll(i);` or `dieRoll;`.

Comment: And `System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieRoll);` is not in the `for` loop scope, the curly brackets around it has no meaning..

Comment: It may be obvious to a seasoned programmer, but for someone new it's not.  Thanks for the help but could you expand a bit more.  I've tried several ways to include the 5 parameters with no luck.  I'm in an online course so it's difficult to get help in a timely manner from the instructor.  I've been searching online and re-reading my book and my instructor videos with little to show for it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is due to the fact that you are trying to pass 1 argument to a function having more than 1 argument. The function call statement should have the exact number of arguments as in the function definition.

Secondly, the print statement you are using is directly printing the function which is not possible. It is better to store the output in a variable and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are Playing the game 100 times by generating random numbers, you need to add the calculation of random numbers in the for loop to generate different numbers.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
 int dice1=(int)(4*Math.random()+i);
 int dice2=(int)(6*Math.random()+i);
 int dice3=(int)(8*Math.random()+i);
 int dice4=(int)(12*Math.random()+i);
 int dice5=(int)(20*Math.random()+i);
 System.out.println("You rolled : "+dieRoll(dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5));
}
```